# Extjs - Not able to hide/unhide actioncolumn icon in specific rows in Grid panel

Tags: extjs, icons, sencha-touch, extjs4.2, gridpanel

I am looking to hide/unhide an icon which I have added in action column based on the row data I get. I tried using the getClass function, but the icon never shows up in any scenario. Without using the getClass function and just using the icon key, I was able to show the icon all the time (commented out in the code below). What am I missing here?

```
this.columns = [{
        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
        itemId:'invalid_icon',
        sortable: false,
        menuDisabled: true,
        cls:'table_invalid_icon',
        width: 70,
        items: [{
            getClass: function(Value, metaData, record){
                if(record.data.name !== 'test' ){
                    return  "hideDisplay";
                }else{
                     return "showIcon";
                }
                    
            }
            //icon: 'image.svg'
        }]
}]
```

I have the corresponding css as below:

```
.showIcon{
   background:url('image.svg'); 
}
.hideDisplay{
  background:none; 
}
```

I have also verified the if condition and the condition has the correct value. Any ideas on what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you use brackground instead of icon property? Is the icon dynamic or static?

```
.hidden {
    display: none
}
```

And working sample:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId: 'employeeStore',
    fields: ['firstname', 'lastname', 'seniority', 'dep', 'hired'],
    data: [{
        firstname: "Michael",
        lastname: "Scott"
    }, {
        firstname: "Dwight",
        lastname: "Schrute"
    }, {
        firstname: "Jim",
        lastname: "Halpert"
    }, {
        firstname: "Kevin",
        lastname: "Malone"
    }, {
        firstname: "Angela",
        lastname: "Martin"
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Action Column Demo',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('employeeStore'),
    columns: [{
        text: 'First Name',
        dataIndex: 'firstname'
    }, {
        text: 'Last Name',
        dataIndex: 'lastname'
    }, {
        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
        width: 50,
        items: [{
            icon: 'https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/extjs-build/examples/shared/icons/fam/cog_edit.png', // Use a URL in the icon config
            tooltip: 'Edit',
            hidden: true,
            getClass: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex) {
                if (rowIndex % 2) {
                    return 'hidden'
                }
            },
            handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                alert("Edit " + rec.get('firstname'));
            }
        }]
    }],
    width: 250,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: the icon is a static icon, somehow I didn't get it to work before, but your solution works for me! Thanks!